# Filter and sort swift array of dictionaries

Tags: ios, swift, filter, swift4

I have the following array:

```
let parent = [ ["Step":"S 3", "Desc":"Do third step" ],
               ["Step":"S 1", "Desc":"Do first step" ],
               ["Step":"S 2", "Desc":"Do second step" ],
                ["Step":"P 1", "Desc":"Some other thing" ] ]
```

How do I filter and sort the array(using filter and sort functions) in the least possible steps so that I get the following output string or label --

1.Do first step

2.Do second step

3.Do third step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let sorted = parent.filter({ ($0["Step"]?.hasPrefix("S"))! }).sorted { $0["Step"]! < $1["Step"]!}
var prefix = 0
let strings = sorted.reduce("") { (partial, next) -> String in
   prefix += 1
   return partial + "\(prefix)." + next["Desc"]! + "\n"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest filtering, sorting, enumerating, mapping, and joining:

```
let results = parent
    .filter { $0["Step"]?.first == "S" }
    .sorted { $0["Step"]!.compare($1["Step"]!, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending }
    .enumerated()
    .map { (index, value) in "\(index + 1). \(value["Desc"]!)" }
    .joined(separator: "\n")
```

A key consideration is the use of `.numeric` comparison, so that "S 10" shows up after "S 9", not between "S 1" and "S 2". You don't want to do simple string comparison if you're embedding a numeric value in your string.

I also threw in that enumeration because if you remove an item, you probably want to make sure that the numbers in your list don't skip over a value just because of the particular encoding inside your `Step` strings.

---

Unrelated, a dictionary is a poor model for something like this. I'd suggest a custom type:

```
struct Task {
    enum TaskType {
        case step
        case process    // or whatever "P" is supposed to stand for
    }

    let sequence: Int
    let type: TaskType
    let taskDescription: String
}

let parent = [Task(sequence: 3, type: .step, taskDescription: "Do third step"),
              Task(sequence: 1, type: .step, taskDescription: "Do first step"),
              Task(sequence: 2, type: .step, taskDescription: "Do second step"),
              Task(sequence: 3, type: .process, taskDescription: "Some other thing")]

let results = parent
    .filter { $0.type == .step }
    .sorted { $0.sequence < $1.sequence }
    .map { "\($0.sequence). \($0.taskDescription)" }
    .joined(separator: "\n")
```

Comment: I liked the case where you discussed numeric comparison and enumeration.

Answer (score 3):

*Described answer:*

**First**, you would need to filter the array to get only steps; Based on the posted `parent` array it seems that the valid step should contain a key as "Step" and a value formatted as "S #", so it could get filtered it as:

```
let filtered = parent.filter { (currentDict) -> Bool in
    // get the value for key "Step"
    guard let value = currentDict["Step"] else {
        return false
    }

    // check ifthe value matches the "S #"
    let trimmingBySpace = value.components(separatedBy: " ")
    if trimmingBySpace.count != 2 || trimmingBySpace[0] != "S" || Int(trimmingBySpace[1]) == nil {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

so far would get:

```
[["Step": "S 3", "Desc": "Do third step"],
 ["Step": "S 1", "Desc": "Do first step"],
 ["Step": "S 2", "Desc": "Do second step"]]
```

**Second**, you would sort the `filtered` array by the value of "Step" key:

```
let sorted = filtered.sorted { $0["Step"]! < $1["Step"]! }
```

and you should get:

```
[["Step": "S 1", "Desc": "Do first step"],
 ["Step": "S 2", "Desc": "Do second step"],
 ["Step": "S 3", "Desc": "Do third step"]]
```

**Finally**, you would map the `sorted` array to get the description values:

```
let descriptions = sorted.map { $0["Desc"] ?? "" }
```

`descriptions` should be:

```
["Do first step", "Do second step", "Do third step"]
```

**All in one step:**

```
let result = parent.filter { (currentDict) -> Bool in
    // get the value for key "Step"
    guard let value = currentDict["Step"] else {
        return false
    }

    // check ifthe value matches the "S #"
    let trimmingBySpace = value.components(separatedBy: " ")
    if trimmingBySpace.count != 2 || trimmingBySpace[0] != "S" || Int(trimmingBySpace[1]) == nil {
        return false
    }

    return true
    }.sorted {
    $0["Step"]! < $1["Step"]!
}.map {
    $0["Desc"] ?? ""
}

print(result) // ["Do first step", "Do second step", "Do third step"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
func sortStep(step1:[String:String], step2:[String:String]) -> Bool {
    guard let s1 = step1["Desc"], let s2 = step2["Desc"] else {
    return false
}
    return s1 < s2
}

let orderedStep = parent.sorted { sortStep(step1:$0, step2:$1) }
print("\(orderedStep)")
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used forced unwrapping assuming that your structure will remain as mentioned. Feel free to add any checks as required.

```
parent.filter { $0["Step"]!.contains("S") }.sorted { $0["Step"]! < $1["Step"]!
}.map { print($0["Desc"]!) }
```